# Recommendations for portable download manager?

Tags: windows, portable, download-manager

I need a portable download manager which can run of Windows 7 / Windows 2008 Server with ability to run on 32/64 bit.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Other then what you've stated, what other criteria? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_download_managers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FreeDownloadManager](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=1364)

Full-featured and portable. Highly recommended!

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can do the job of download managers. so if you want something small and easy use [Opera.](http://www.opera.com)

Comment: Opera? *Small?* :D (Seriously though, its download manager does not offer anything that Firefox or Chrome wouldn't.)

Comment: Well yes it is small and easy. 33mb to Chrome's 190mb for me now, but the portable versions I use on Windows it's more like 8 and 30mb.